# IIS hosted WCF service with digest authentification

Tags: wcf, iis

I want to create a WCF service hosted in IIS 7.5 and I want to use digest authentification over http.

I have setup digest on virtual directory but when I try to access the service I always get error:

> *this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled
>   for the IIS application that hosts this service*

This is my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding_IServisTest">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Digest"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="ServisService.ServisTest" 
           behaviorConfiguration="ServisService.ServisTestBehavior">
     <endpoint 
         address="" 
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_IServisTest"
         contract="ServisService.IServistest" >
     </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServisService.ServisTestBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm using http not https.

Comment: Have you disabled anonymous authentication in IIS for the virtual directory?  Also, have you already configured kerberos for the two machines?

Comment: Yes, I disabled anonimous authentification on virtual directory. When is enabled I can access service and I don't wont to be accessible without authentification.

Comment: how about kerberos?  are you using AD for authentication?

Comment: I'm using AD for autentification. I have enabled "store passwords using reversible encryption" on that account. I can access other files in virtual directory.

Comment: I have also enabled "Use DES encryption type for this account"

Answer (score 0):

For this I guess Security Mode should be transport

```
<security mode="Transport">
```

This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/a27fabba-3798-45bf-941b-315bffbbccd2) might help you.

Comment: `<security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Digest" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />`